# Create a wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've few questions about the custom post type in Wordpress.

a) I read that custom post type code should be embedded in a plugin. Is that really necessary?

b) Is the declaration `add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );` supposed to stay forever, or once added for the first time can be later removed?

c) How can I programmatically add the content and associate it to my custom post type?

Thanks.

Comment: You can create custom post types for your theme. They definitely do not need to be created in a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Try to imagine the moment of changing themes, do you really want to move all this functionality from one theme `functions` file to another? And repeat this at every theme change?
See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

b) Yes, it must run at every `init`. There's no problem with that.

c) This is way too broad, but you can start a research here and at WordPress Development with the function [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).